# Chose a course using f.select and automatically entered into the field count_stud value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a form in which we choose the year and course. Another field is not visible (it should change the number of students, which corresponds to the selected course).Сhose a course using f.select and automatically entered into the field count_stud value equal to the number of students on this course. How to do this? Probably need JavaScript (Ajax technology)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ajax` you can do this,
change your select like below

```
 <%= f.select(:course_id, @courses.map{|p| [p.id]},{},{:class => "course_id"}) %>
```

year:

```
 <%= f.select(:year_id, @years.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]} ,{},{:onchange => "update_student(this.value)"}) %>
```

text box:

```
<%= f.text_field :count_stud, :value => @student_count,:class => "student" %>
```

in ajax code:

```
function update_student(year) {  
 var course = jQuery(".course_id").val(); // finding course value
 if(course == ""){                        // checking course value being selected or not
   alert("Please select course ");
   return false;
 }
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "update_student",
 type: "GET",
 data: {"course_id" : course,"year": year },
 dataType: "text",
 success: function(data) {
 jQuery(".student").val(data); // inserting response to text field.
 }
 });
}
```

so,`onchange` of the course select box one ajax request will go with year and course value,then in your action you get the values in `params` and find the `no of student` and return like 
in `YearCoursesController`

```
   def update_student
      year = params[:year]
      course = params[:course]
      #write logic to find student
      #assign in one variable 
      year_courses = YearCourse.find_by(year_id: year, course_id: course)
      student_count = year_courses ? year_courses.students.count : 0
      render :text => student_count  #we are returning the value
   end
```

then that value will insert to the text box.

Comment: Explain in more detail where that. I got confused. The ajax code gives out mistakes.

Comment: no work. What it is necessary to write in the controler in new and create action? to count students?                                 render: text = your_student_value and here this line where? Please, help!

Comment: check the student value?

Comment: <%= f.text_field :count_stud, :value => @student_count.:class => "student" %> is true? or

Comment: <%= f.text_field :count_stud, :value => @student_count, :class => "student" %> - true?

Comment: change `<%= f.text_field :count_stud, @student_count, :class => "student" %>` then `def update_student` in that method check `student_value`?

Comment: I specified the word (mistake) where there are mistakes in the my post. And at (select) the page in general isn't refreshed.

Comment: I badly think in javascript

Comment: There are no errors in ajax code, but this form no work.

Comment: ajax request is going or not? check in browser console press `F12` ?

Comment: In the field of count_stud value isn't brought at all. The page at a choice of a course isn't refreshed. At the table student following fields: id, name, surname, course_id. At the table year_courses: id, course_id, year_id, count_stud. At the table of courses: id. At the table of years: id, name. Year doesn't play value. Plays value the chosen course.

Comment: and what has to be in new action?

Comment: def new
  courses = Course.all
  years = Year.all
  year_course = YearCourse.new
  end

Comment: don't understand!                                                  def new
  courses = Course.all
  years = Year.all
  year_course = YearCourse.new
  end

Comment: --
[22:08:30.604] GET http://localhost:3000/year_courses/update_student?course_id=1&year=2 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  44ms] - console js - at change of year